# Extjs 5 - LoadMask on the entire page not working

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

In Extjs 4.2, I was using Load Mask for the whole page

In a common utility class :

```
loadMask: null,
showLoading : function() {
    if (!this.loadMask) {
      this.loadMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), { msg: "Loading..." });
    }
    this.loadMask.show();
  },

  clearLoading:function() {
    this.loadMask.hide();
  },
```

I was calling this method in the all the pages during loading/saving (waiting for the server side response ), but in Extjs 5.0, it is not working, I am getting the following error message :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'mask' of undefined all-classes.js:1
Ext.define.show all-classes.js:1
Ext.define.loadingProcess all-classes.js:1
Ext.define.listeners.beforeload all-classes.js:1
Ext.define.doFire all-classes.js:1
Ext.define.fire all-classes.js:1
Ext.define.doDispatchEvent all-classes.js:1
Ext.define.dispatchEvent all-classes.js:1
Ext.define.doFireEvent all-classes.js:1
a.doFireEvent all-classes.js:1
Ext.define.fireEvent all-classes.js:1
Ext.define.load
```

Comment: Just a side note - `null == this.loadMask` is no better than `!this.loadMask`

Comment: :) thanks, i will update it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got it !!! It is changed in Extjs 5.0, Ext.getBody() returns the Ext.dom.Element and for Element use mask() and unmask(), so it should be

```
  //mask
 Ext.getBody().mask("Loading...");

//unmask
 Ext.getBody().unmask();
```

Comment: you could also just use `.setLoading(true)` and `.setLoading(false)`.

Comment: `maskElement: 'body'` - lets one assign what to mask (a panel config).

Comment: Just a clarification, 'body' does *not* mean that the <body> will be masked, setting it tells ext to mask the 'body' of the component rather than the 'el'. (For example, if you want toolbar buttons to still be clickable) http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.LoadMask.html#cfg-maskElement